# tail() function in XQuery

Tags: function, xquery, tail, marklogic

Is there a way in **XQuery** to do something like a `tail()` function?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the contents of a file (using "**xdmp:filesystem-file($path)**") and then display only the last 100 lines. I can't seem to find a good way to do this. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two different pure XPath 2.0 solutions that are more portable and usable than a XQuery-specific solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

In plain XQuery, this can be accomplished by splitting into lines and getting the desired number of lines from the end of the sequence, then rejoining them, if necessary, i.e.

```
declare function local:tail($content as xs:string, $number as xs:integer)
{
  let $linefeed := "&#10;"
  let $lines := tokenize($content, $linefeed)
  let $tail := $lines[position() > last() - $number]
  return string-join($tail, $linefeed)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**A pure  and short XPath 2.0 solution** -- can be used not only in XQuery but in XSLT or in any other PL hosting XPath 2.0:

```
for $numLines in count(tokenize(., '&#xA;'))
  return
    tokenize(., '&#xA;')[position() gt $numLines -100]
```

**Or**:

```
for $numLines in count(tokenize(., '&#xA;'))
 return
    subsequence(tokenize(., '&#xA;'), $numLines -100 +1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your xdmp:file-xx is a nature of text file then you could use something like

```
let $f := 'any file system path'
return fn:tokenize(xdmp:filesystem-file($f), '[\n\r]+')[ fn:last() - 2 to fn:last()]
```

here 
  i have used newline & carriage return as my token splitter. if you need something else to tokenize u could. but simple log file tailing then this solution works fine.

given example tails last 2 lines of a given file. if you want more than alter fn:last()-2 to fn:last() - x